# fail to get current time in c

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, datetime

I have seen this [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_date_and_time_functions):

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t current_time;
    char* c_time_string;

    /* Obtain current time as seconds elapsed since the Epoch. */
    current_time = time(NULL);
```

however while debugging in eclipse I see in the `watch` area:

`time(NULL)    error evaluating`

even though I have

`#include <time.h>`

how can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code that I can see, but that error is a debugger message, it doesn't mean that you program isn't working.

Comment: Is your program actually not working, or are you just annoyed by the debugger warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
  time_t timer;
  time(&timer);  /* get current time; same as: timer = time(NULL)  */
```

example from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/)

Answer (score 3):

Your debugger isn't smart enough to evaluate time(NULL), there isn't any fix except don't type 'time(NULL)' into the expressions window.